# run time failure with Mqtt client.connect

Tags: c#, runtime-error, client, mqtt, mosquitto

The C# program (on win10 laptop) is publishing to the Mosquitto server (on Ubuntu laptop) every 1 second.
Both laptops are connected by Wifi, on same local network.
It is working well. Mostly.

After every ~500 cycles, a run time error occurs:

`uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Exception connecting to the broker
  Source=M2Mqtt.Net`

The code that generated the error:

```
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IP_ADDR);           
        byte code = client.Connect(new Guid().ToString(), null, null, true, 10);
        if (code==0)
        { .......
```

I can understand that connection may fail, yet I would expect the return code to be a non zero value in such a case, and not a run time exception.
I know  I can put in a "TRY" , yet I wonder how can I solve it in a better way.

Thank you

Comment: Not answering your question, but why are you creating a new connection (with a new client id) every second rather than just keeping a connection alive for the lifetime of the app?

Comment: @hardillb: good question, I am not sure myself. It started when I was trying to reach one message to go through. Then I just added a loop to test it. I am still learning mqtt. At that time (yesterday) I didn't know how to check if it is still connected. Now I know. At this stage, I want to understand why the run time error occurs, and I will change it once solved.

Comment: @hardillb : Now the connection is created one time, and the loop run 100 times OK, I will let it run overnight for better testing. One thing I still miss is that how I verify the message was delivered to the subscriber.

Comment: You don't, there is no end to end delivery notification in the MQTT protocol. Look at the QOS levels (these apply independently to both publishing and subscribing) to get assured delivery to as many subscribers as there may be (pub/sub is a way to totally decouple publishers from subscribers) there may be 0 to n subscribers to any given topic...